# Close all figures in MATLAB, except specific ones.

Tags: matlab, figure, figures

I am trying to determine if there is a nice way, to close all figures in MATLAB, *except* for one(s) that I determine before hand, are not to be closed. Is there such a way to do this?

I am finding that I am wasting a lot of time chasing down specific stuff to close, every time my MATLAB script runs. Thank you.

Comment: Google search resulted in the following link, which has the function that does exactly what you are looking for: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24420-close-all-figures-except-those-listed

Comment: glad to help, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this

```
%figures to keep
figs2keep = [4, 7];

% Uncomment the following to 
% include ALL windows, including those with hidden handles (e.g. GUIs)
% all_figs = findall(0, 'type', 'figure');

all_figs = findobj(0, 'type', 'figure');
delete(setdiff(all_figs, figs2keep));
```

Here's the [link to the source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24420-close-all-figures-except-those-listed)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the safest way is to assign handles to variables `h1, h2, ...` for each of your figures as you generate them and then use `close(handle)` to close the figures you don't want open.

`close()` also takes a vector/matrix of handles as an input, so you could always aggregate a vector of handles of figures to be closed.

Comment: Well, the problem is that things are changing very quickly, this isnt a 'nice' environment, lots of research going on. So more often than not, I have umpteen figures open, but I want all closed now except for figures 7 and 4. So, I am hoping for a solution that would just take those two arguments, [4 7], and close everything else.